# regex pattern repetition

Tags: javascript, regex

regex noob here, i created a regex validator for my input, i'm trying to validate the following :

```
{ word } //valid
{ word } ; { word } //also valid
```

so i came up with this :

```
^[\s]*\{[a-zA-z\s]*\}[\s]*$|^[\s]*\{[a-zA-z\s]*\}[\s]*\;[\s]*[\s]*\{[a-zA-z\s]*\}[\s]*$
```

it works but the problem is i cant add anything after that. i want to repeat the " ; { word } " part as much as needed. How can i do this ?

Comment: Use a [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Comment: you mean { word } ; { word } ; { word } ; .... is valid ? and does it have to be space at the begining and end of word ?

Comment: { word } ; { word } ; { word } is valid. the final character shouldn't be ";". And yes  it have to be space at the begining and end of word

Comment: and the word can be any charachter or only alphab. ?

Comment: Use `^\s*{\s*[a-zA-Z]+\s*}\s*(?:;\s*{\s*[a-zA-Z]+\s*})*\s*$`, see https://regex101.com/r/zL6UXY/1

Comment: Works like a cham. Thank you :)

Comment: had to edit a couple times but there we go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/^\s*{\s*[a-zA-Z]+\s*}\s*(?:;\s*{\s*[a-zA-Z]+\s*}\s*)*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zL6UXY/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*{\s*[a-zA-Z]+\s*}\s*` - a `{` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces, 1+ ASCII letters, and then a `}` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:` - a start of a non-capturing group:

  - `;` - a semi-colon
  - `\s*{\s*[a-zA-Z]+\s*}\s*` - a `{` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces, 1+ ASCII letters, and then a `}` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `)*` - zero or more times
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
^((\{\s?[a-zA-Z]+\s?\}\s?;\s?)+)?(\{\s?[a-zA-Z]+\s?\}\s?;?\s?){1}$
```

matches all of these cases:

```
{ word }
{word}
{ word } ; { word } ; { word }
{ word } ; { word }
{word};{word};{word}
{word};{word}
{ word } ; { word } ; { word } ;
{ word } ; { word } ;
{word};{word};{word};
{word};{word};
```

Comment: `\w` also matches `_` and digits. OP did not mean to match them.

Comment: you are right, i will change \w for [a-zA-Z], thanks.